# SOA Architecture Real-World Samples with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, soa

Any SOA Architecture (n-tier) Real-World Samples with .NET for getting started ?

Comment: @animuson 6 years later this question got 6 answers. The question got 13 upvotes. Where's the 'too many possible answers' or whatever concern? I hate it when a single person closes useful questions for no very good reason. Let it be.. and don't point me to the rules like a robot.

Answer (score 14):

I recommend to start a .NET App with WCF. Get related to WCF, its advantages a as to expose a service endpoint with multiple binding as http, tcp, etc, so you are able to SOA your App.

I use the UML [Robustness Analysis](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/robustnessDiagram.htm) to discover the functionality that will be exposed as services.

I think that there is not silver bullet code for SOA, SOA is about design, organization of the system methods in order to expose services that orchestrates the handling of the responsibilities of application entities.

For example, to look for a flight booking, your SOA service have to expose a contract, with all necessary data to handle the service request. It will return all necesary data for the next service, book flight.

There is an excelent article about SOA in the [Architecture Journal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/architecture/bb410935.aspx) #21 -Service Orientation Today and Tomorrow  Article An [Enterprise Architecture Strategy for SOA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/architecture/aa699438.aspx) written by Hatay Tuna.

SOA is about logic exposure, design, logic ecapsulation, is not about code, the code supports the orientation.

Comment: Isn't WCF dying or already dead?

Answer (score 4):

Here it is.

[Realizing a Service-Oriented Architecture with .NET](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/031215.htm)

[Service-Oriented Architecture and Microsoft .NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/john_charles/Service_Oriented_Architecture_and_Microsoft_NET01202006080616AM/Service_Oriented_Architecture_and_Microsoft_NET.aspx)

Comment: First link is not working.

Comment: Update for first link: https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/article.php/c19627/Realizing-a-ServiceOriented-Architecture-with-NET.htm

Answer (score 3):

I'm about to study [.NET StockTrader 6 Sample Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb499684.aspx).

> The Azure StockTrader 6 application is an end-to-end sample application for Windows Azure. It is a **service-oriented application** based on Windows Communication Foundation and ASP.NET, with a RESTful backend hosted on Windows Azure. It includes cross-platform clients for HTML5, Windows 8, Windows Phone, Android and iOS that connect to the Azure Cloud Services backend. The backend database is Windows Azure SQL Database, and the application optionally supports scale-out via SQL Database Federation.

I've got linked from this place: http://androtan.wordpress.com/2007/11/20/interesting-soa-wcf-and-aspnet-case-study/

However, IMO, it seems much more like a technical side example, perhaps just a good SOAD topic.

Answer (score 2):

I have forked and extended and written a sample application called [Documently](https://github.com/haf/Documently) which implements SOA using TopShelf, MassTransit and RabbitMQ.

Comment: https://github.com/haf/Documently/tree/develop - this branch contains all the latest code. Missing from this SOA example are things like provisioning; how to actually deploy the code, as well as how to orchestrate things which wasn't needed for the sample.